# Channgel entry to disabled

Tags: entries, localization, channels

Is it possible that when my user adds a new entry in a channel on the English site, it gets copied to the channel of my Belgian site, but this entry is set automatically to disabled?

So my English user adds a blog item and enables them, they are copied to my Belgian website but they are disabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Under Settings > Sections > [section] > Site Settings, you can set the Default Status per-site for new entries in that section.

[image: Screenshot of Craft CMS section settings for multi-site]

For copying the actual content, set the appropriate "Propagation Method" setting underneath. Note that the propagation only happens on the first save. If you need to overwrite/sync content across sites after the first save, there's the Sync Sites plugin: https://github.com/timkelty/craftcms-site-sync

Comment: Thanks for your reply James!